# Getting a `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Tags: python

```
bill = input("What is your total amount? ")

persent = float(input("How much you wanna tip? 10%, 12% or 15%? "))

ppl = input("How many ppl are spliting the bill? ")

T = (persent / 100)

Bill = (bill * T)
```

I tried making it in to a int variable but that doesn't make since because the bill can be a float or a int.

Comment: Did you try making `bill` a float, the same way you did `percent`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert bill to either a float or an int after accepting the value from the first input.  Example:

```
bill = float(input("What is your total amount? "))
```

Comment: So does the ppl

Comment: @WaketZheng ppl is not used in the example code, you are right though!